# Emotion styled component and React.forwardRef not working together

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I'm trying to write two React styled components (with Emotion 10), specifying some custom render logic into one of them, and preserving the ability to retrieve their "refs".

This is my code:

```
const Foo = styled(props => <div {...props} />)`
  color: red;
`;

// Here I **want** to use the component selector
// https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#targeting-another-emotion-component
const Bar = styled.div`
  ${Foo} {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  return <Bar><Foo ref={ref}>foo</Foo></Bar>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

The issue with this code is that React throws this warning:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

As we know, Emotion styled components make use of `React.forwardRef` to enable developers to use the `ref` property on them. But it seems to not work as soon you switch to a custom render method.

Then, if I (awkwardly<sup>[1]</sup>) convert it to use `React.forwardRef` what I get is:

```
const Foo = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const Component = styled(props => <div {...props} />)`
    color: red;
  `;
  return <Component {...props} ref={ref} />;
});

const Bar = styled.div`
  ${Foo} {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  return <Bar><Foo ref={ref}>foo</Foo></Bar>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

But then, I get a different error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Which is happening where I try to use `${Foo}`. Probably because Emotion expects a styled component but I'm now providing a `forwardRef` component.

Here's a CodeSandbox to make it easier to play with my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7ylnlovlz6

So, what's the proper way to achieve what I'm trying to get?

[1]: *I know defining a component inside a render will make the component re-render on each render, but it's irrelevant in this context.*

Comment: Did you try wrapping your component with React.frowardRef?

Comment: Can you throw it in an online REPL? will be easier to help.

Comment: I was just trying to combine Emotion + Pose + Typescript, had similar issues, managed to solve it now :)

Comment: You had some issues - https://codesandbox.io/s/p7ky3w4y47?fontsize=14
Is that what you were aiming towards?

Comment: In this case they give you the same result, yeah, there seems to be an issues, cause with object notation it works.

Comment: @alexunder what do you mean? With object notation it doesn't throw errors but the rule is completely ignored.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ox5nx6o705

Answer (score 2):

Now you don't need to do anything. Emotion handles ref correctly.
This code will work.

```
const Foo = styled(props => <div {...props} />)`
  color: red;
`;

const Bar = styled.div`
  ${Foo} {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  return <Bar><Foo ref={ref}>foo</Foo></Bar>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Comment: "Now"? Did this get fixed in a specific version?